# purpose of "wird" from "werden" in the present tense for "teuer"

Tags: verb

I know that **werden** is needed to form the future tense, and in the present tense, it means roughly "to become."

However, in the following sentence:

> Herr Maier möchte eine Weltreise machen, obwohl es sehr teuer wird.

I failed to work out the meaning of the second subordinate clause

> obwohl es sehr teuer wird.

Does wird ( = made from "werden") function the same way as "sein" i.e.

> Mr Maier wants to make a trip around the world, even though it is very expensive.

Comment: Could be as well _"teuer sein/werden wird"_. A translation I would use would be _"Mr Maier wants to make a trip around the world, even though it is **going to be**  very expensive."_

Answer (score 3):

Some verbs are so called *copula* (coupler), they simply connect two items. The typical copula verbs in German are *sein*, *werden* and *bleiben*:

> Eine Weltreise ist teuer.

*A world trip is expensive.*

> Eine Weltreise wird teuer.

*A world trip is going to be expensive.*

> Eine Weltreise bleibt teuer.

*A world trip keeps being expensive.*

---

There are some more verbs which can act as couplers. You can tell those verbs in their copula mode by the *Prädikativ* they take then. That's either a noun phrase in nominative case or an adjective phrase in ending-less form.

> Du siehst **gut** aus.
>
> Das klingt/schmeckt/riecht **gut**.
>
> Das erscheint mir reichlich **spät**.
>
> Er heißt **Bob Smith**.
>
> Das gilt als **ein Fehler**.
>
> Es erwies sich als **die Lösung**.
>
> Es kommt **selten** vor.